# Slow UEFI boot ("loading initial ramdisk" takes 20s.)

Tags: grub, uefi

I installed Debian testing (stretch) on a HP ZBook Studio G3,

Everything works fine, but booting spends approximatively 20 seconds on "loading initial ramdisk".

The system is in UEFI mode, /boot/efi exists and contains files.

During boot, I get the following messages:

```
[ 0.000000 ] efi: requested map not found
[ 0.000000 ] esrt: ESRT header is not in the memory map
```

(but the system works, my only concern is that "loading initial ramdisk" takes 20 seconds).

The disk is a SSD, partitioned as follows:

```
fdisk /dev/nvme0n1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2F170DB6-D4DE-4E94-B54D-12717000A293

Device           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem
```